# $2$ equal improper integrals but one integral converges absolutely other is not

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I can show by parts 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1+x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^2}dx$$.

But How to argue that one of them is converging absolutely and other is not?

Is it possible to argue using integral test ? like $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^2}dx$ $\leq \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin x|}{(1+x)^2}dx$ which is convergent  by integral test as $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ is convergent .

Or there is other way to show .Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Note: Just because two integrals have an equal answer, does not mean that both integrals have to be absolute convergent...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second integrand has absolute value bounded by $1/(1+x)^2$
which has a finite integral. On the other side one has absolute value
$$\frac{|\cos x|}{1+x}.$$
The numerator has period $\pi$, so that
$$\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{|\cos x|}{1+x}\,dx
\ge\frac1{1+(n+1)\pi}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}|\cos x|\,dx
=\frac{A}{1+(n+1)\pi}$$
where
$$A=\int_0^\pi|\cos x|\,dx>0.$$
So
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{|\cos x|}{1+x}\,dx\ge\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac A{1+(n+1)\pi}$$
which is a divergent series.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach: the absolute convergence of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{(x+1)^2}\,dx$ is trivial, but the function $\left|\cos x\right|$ has a positive mean value ($\frac{2}{\pi}$), hence the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x+1}\,dx$ *is not* absolutely convergent by [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma).